# How to preserve compatibility when loading NSPersistentDocument(s) saved using a modified entity model?

Tags: cocoa, core-data

I've created an OSX app that uses the entity model builder and its related stuff, for simplicity consider the entity with only two NSString.

The app is in production and works fine, now I need to add new attributes to the existing entity (only one entity exists), but with new attributes the old saved files are not open, silently the app does't open them and the console doesn't contain any error/warning message.

I need to load old saved files, consider all new attributes are optionals and have defaults (also in code not only in model design)
All existing attributes continue to be present I've only **added** the new attrs.

How can I design applications able to work when the entity model change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From OS X 10.5 onwards, there is data migration functionality to help you, as long as you make changes to the data model in a new version.

There is a good basic explanation and example here: http://www.timisted.net/blog/archive/core-data-migration/

and the Apple documentation is here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html